# javascript regex for special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a validation for a password field which allows only the `a-zA-Z0-9` characters and `.!@#$%^&*()_+-=`

I can't seem to get the hang of it.

What's the difference when using `regex = /a-zA-Z0-9/g and regex = /[a-zA-Z0-9]/` and which chars from `.!@#$%^&*()_+-=` are needed to be escaped?

What I've tried up to now is:

```
var regex = /a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-/g
```

but with no success

Comment: Stop it.  There should not be any limitation on the characters you can use for a password.  The most restriction there should be is a quota for what types of characters *must* appear.  But if i want to have a password like `ag90:"jNn;fsi./`, why shouldn't that be allowed?

Comment: @cHao maybe give a regex for doing so then ... ;)

Comment: @jamiebarrow: `/^(.*\W){3}.*$/` would require at least 3 non-word characters...but that wouldn't answer the question.  :)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g
```

Should work

Also may want to have a minimum length i.e. 6 characters

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]{6,}$/g
```

Comment: Doesn't this disallow every character inside the brackets? (Including our beloved alphabet?)

Comment: Oh sorry, I had the metacharacters in regexs mixed up. Please ignore my previous comment.

Comment: comma fails isnt it special character ? `var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#\$%\^\&*\)\(+=._-]+$/g;  regex.test('happy,');
` gives false reference https://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html

Answer (score 50):

a sleaker way to match special chars:

```
/\W|_/g
```

**\W** Matches any character that is not a word character (alphanumeric & underscore).

Underscore is considered a special character so
add boolean to either match a special character or _

Comment: Be advised: this will match any non-latin characters, as well.

Comment: Characters like `ñ` are also considered special in this case so be careful

Comment: i liked this one

Answer (score 15):

You can be specific by testing for not valid characters. This will return true for anything not alphanumeric and space:

```
var specials = /[^A-Za-z 0-9]/g;
return specials.test(input.val());
```

Comment: simply and perfect

Answer (score 13):

> What's the difference?

`/[a-zA-Z0-9]/` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches one character that is inside the class. It consists of three ranges.

`/a-zA-Z0-9/` does mean the literal sequence of those 9 characters.

> Which chars from `.!@#$%^&*()_+-=` are needed to be escaped?

Inside a character class, only the minus (if not at the end) and the circumflex (if at the beginning). Outside of a charclass, `.$^*+()` have a special meaning and need to be escaped to match literally.

> allows only the `a-zA-Z0-9` characters and `.!@#$%^&*()_+-=`

Put them in a character class then, let them [repeat](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) and require to match the whole string with them by [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%\^&*)(+=._-]*$/
```

Answer (score 11):

Complete set of special characters:

```
/[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\)\(\+\=\.\<\>\{\}\[\]\:\;\'\"\|\~\`\_\-]/g
```

To answer your question:

```
var regular_expression = /^[A-Za-z0-9\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\)\(+\=\._-]+$/g
```

Answer (score 8):

How about this:-

```
var regularExpression = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*]{6,}$/;
```

It will allow a minimum of 6 characters including numbers, alphabets, and special characters

Comment: Why a maximum length?

Comment: @11684 - Perhaps because it needs to eventually stored in a fixed size entry in a database?

Comment: Well, we don't know that, but if, then I'd ask why there was such a low fixed entry size in the first place. @EdHeal

Comment: @11684- I suppose Rahul done that as an example. Besides PIN numbers for ATMs are just 4 digits. The banks seem to be happy with that. 6 characters would be even harder to guess!

Comment: @rahul various special characters like []{}<>/"' are missing.

Answer (score 5):

There are some issue with above written Regex.

This works perfectly.

```
^[a-zA-Z\d\-_.,\s]+$
```

Only allowed special characters are included here and can be extended after comma.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Regex for special symbols

var regex_symbols= /[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:\/;<>?,.@#]/;
```

Answer (score 4):

This regex works well for me to validate password:

```
/[ !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~]/
```

This list of special characters (including white space and punctuation) was taken from here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_special_characters. It was changed a bit, cause backslash ('\') and closing bracket (']') had to be escaped for proper work of the regex. That's why two additional backslash characters were added.

Comment: Thanx for this and for the link to OWASP list of special characters, very useful!

Answer (score 3):

Regex for minimum 8 char, one alpha, one numeric and one special char:

```
/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])[A-Za-z\d!@#$%^&*]{8,}$/
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the actual regex only match:

```
/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[:;<>?,.@#\]]/g
```

Comment: Thanks! wordpress_designer.
Your solution worked for me. I only needed the characters for my script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to find and replace any special characters like in Worpress's slug

```
const regex = /[`~!@#$%^&*()-_+{}[\]\\|,.//?;':"]/g
let slug = label.replace(regex, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nameInput(limitField)
{
//LimitFile here is a text input and this function is passed to the text 
onInput
var inputString = limitField.value;
// here we capture all illegal chars by adding a ^ inside the class,
// And overwrite them with "".
var newStr = inputString.replace(/[^a-zA-Z-\-\']/g, "");
limitField.value = newStr;
}
```

This function only allows alphabets, both lower case and upper case and - and ' characters. May help you build yours.

Comment: The question appears to focus on handling the characters `.!@#$%^&*()_+-=`. Does this answer address that portion of the question?

Comment: I haven't tried those characters yet but with the structure of the regex, all you have to do to handle those characters is to put them in the expression. I'm guessing something like /[^a-zA-Z-\-\'.!@\$%\^\(\)_+]/g. All you have to do is escape characters that represent special functions in regex expressions like $^()

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in React Native:

```
[~_!@#$%^&*()\\[\\],.?":;{}|<>=+()-\\s\\/`\'\]
```

Here's my reference for the list of special characters:

- https://owasp.org/www-community/password-special-characters

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If we need to allow only **number and symbols (- and .)** then we can use the following pattern

```
const filterParams = {
    allowedCharPattern: '\\d\\-\\.', // declaring regex pattern
    numberParser: text => {
        return text == null ? null : parseFloat(text)
    }
}
```