# Wordpress- block characters in custom input field

Tags: wordpress, input, character, block

Can enybody help me with block special characters in my custom field in front-end? I want add this block only for one field with specific #id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a look at this: [JavaScript Real Time Text Input or Textarea Filter Tutorial.](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Real-Time-Text-Input-or-Textarea-Filter-Tutorial)

The basic principle would be to check whether the user enters something that is not allowed (regular expression in JavaScript) and then strip that character or something like that.

If you are looking out for Regular Expressions and JavaScript, Stack Overflow [already has something nice for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812317/javascript-regex-for-special-characters)

Comment: Well dobę! It was very helpfull :)