# Get first specific special character that occurs in a string

Tags: javascript

How can I extract the first special character (allowing only `#` and `.`) from a string?

For example:

`svg#hello` would return `#`

`-hello-world#testing` would return `#`

`-hello-world.testing` would return `.`

`.test` would return `.`

and so on?

Comment: `str.match(/[#.]/)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript regex for special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812317/javascript-regex-for-special-characters)

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match for an explanation of adeneo's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.match(/[#.]/)` on your strings to match the characters you want:

```js
var texts = ['svg#hello', '-hello-world#testing', '-hello-world.testing', '.test'];
var regex = '[#.]';

// You need to add the [0] to get the element of the array returned by the function
console.log(
  texts[0].match(regex)[0],
  texts[1].match(regex)[0],
  texts[2].match(regex)[0],
  texts[3].match(regex)[0]
);
```

---

If you ever want to extend it to other special chars, you may want to use a reversed regex like `.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/)` on your strings, to match the non letters, non numbers and not `-` characters:

```js
var texts = ['svg#hello', '-hello-world#testing', '-hello-world.testing', '.test', '_new-test'];
var regex = '[^a-zA-Z0-9-]';

// You need to add the [0] to get the element of the array returned by the function
console.log(
  texts[0].match(regex)[0],
  texts[1].match(regex)[0],
  texts[2].match(regex)[0],
  texts[3].match(regex)[0],
  texts[4].match(regex)[0]
);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why didn't you use the regex in adeneo's comment? The question specifically says "allowing only `#` and `.`".

Comment: I admit I must have missed it when reading the question. I've edited, thanks @DavidKnipe