# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in javascript django app

Tags: javascript, python, django

This is my function:

```
function convert_strings() {
var chart_labels = {{ chartlabels }};
var array_length = chart_labels.length;
for (var i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    chart_labels[i] = chart_labels[i].replace(/&#039;/g, "'")
    }
return chart_labels
}
```

This is my error: 
"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &"

```
function convert_strings() {
var chart_labels = [&#39;CHENNAI LPG RO&#39;, &#39;KOCHI LPG RO&#39;, &#39;BANGALORE LPG RO&#39;, &#39;HUBLI LPG RO&#39;, &#39;MADURAI LPG RO&#39;, &#39;MANGLORE LPG RO&#39;];
var array_length = chart_labels.length;
for (var i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    chart_labels[i] = chart_labels[i].replace(/&#039;/g, "'")
    }
return chart_labels
}
```

Please advice what to do :)

Comment: The declaration of your `chart_labels` array isn't valid. You're missing quotes.

Comment: @Zenoo: I think these were added, but *escaped* :). The data should be turned into a non-escaped JSON blob.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It doesn't make much sense, since he's trying to remove those escaped quotes in the next RegEx.

Comment: @Zenoo: that is exactly to remove the escaping, but since it is not escaping in a string, of course it does not work. But trying to rewrite code literals with string processing, is unfortunately something one sees often here :(.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem how to convert my data into non-escaped JSON blobs. I want my data to be an array of strings.

Comment: `/&#39;/g` you are having a `0` in your regular exp. remove that to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view, you can convert the `chartlabels` to a JSON blob, for example with:

```
import json

def some_view(request):
    # ...
    context['chartlabels_json'] = json.dumps(context['chartlabels'])
    # ...
    return render(request, 'some_template.html', context)
```

In the template, we can then write the blob in an unescaped way:

```
function convert_strings() {
    return {{ chartlabels_json|safe }};
}
```

A more convenient way is however probably using the [**`django-jsonify`** [PyPI]](https://pypi.org/project/django-jsonify/) tool, and thus simply pass the `charlabel` through the `jsonify` filter.

Comment: This works when the script is included in the html, but it doesn't work when the javascript file is external adn being loaded with the `Media` class. Instead, `return {{ chartlabels_json|safe }};` results in a syntax error on the second "{". And when I do `return "{{ chartlabels_json|safe }}";`, I end up with that exact string.  So, got any solutions for external javascript?

Comment: @JoshuaSwain: this will of course not work, since Django does not *render* static files (in production, it does not even serve static files either), and Django only works at the backend so the template tags do not "*work*" at the frontend. You should make the external script in such way that it accepts a parameter with the JSON object.

Answer (score 2):

`{{ chart_labels|safe }}`

This would do it. No need to use .replace or jsonDump

Answer (score 0):

Use the following, for more details on creating the regex for special characters follows this links [javascript regex for special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812317/javascript-regex-for-special-characters):

```js
var str = '&#39;CHENNAI LPG RO&#39;'
console.log(str.replace(/\&\#39;/g, "'"));
```