# regex - minimum of 6 characters including 2 special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not very confortable with regex. I would like the password to have a minimum of 6 characters, including 2 special characters

I tried a first regex but it just returns false each time...

```js
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9!$#%]+$/.test(this.form.password));
```

I can test the number of characters another way but I would like to include the two special characters through the regex.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812317/javascript-regex-for-special-characters/18812336

Comment: *"I am not very confortable with regex"* try another approach, then. A loop can do the job

Answer (score 0):

First lookahead for 6 characters, to ensure that enough exist in the input. Then, repeat twice: 0 or more normal characters, followed by a special character, to ensure that there are at least 2 special characters in the input. Then match 0 or more [special or normal] characters.

```
/^(?=.{6})(?:[a-z\d]*[!$#%]){2}[a-z\d!$#%]*$/i
```

https://regex101.com/r/ZyFZPm/2

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?=.{6})` - At least 6 characters
- `(?:[a-z\d]*[!$#%]){2}` - Repeat twice:

  - `[a-z\d]*` - 0+ alphanumeric characters
  - `[!$#%]` - 1 special character
- `[a-z\d!$#%]*` - Match both special and alphanumeric characters up to the end of the string
- `$` - End of string