# Javascript Special Character Password Validation without JQuery

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords, special-characters

I would like to write a simple if statement to test for special characters. Something like this:

```
var passwordSpecial = **WHATDOIPUTHERE???**.test(password)
if(passwordSpecial == true){
var pass="OK"
}
else{
var pass="NO"
}
```

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: check this so question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812317/javascript-regex-for-special-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const pattern = new RegExp(/^[^@]+$/);
const password1 = pattern.test("hey")
const password2 = pattern.test("@hey")

//returns true, false
console.log(password1, password2)
```

anything you put inside the brackets after the "^" won't be allowed in the string, in this case "@"

Edit: see this code pen
https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/vYLeYqp?editors=1011

And if you want to specifically only allow numbers and letters

```
const pattern = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/);
```

It depends on your definition of what a special character is.

Comment: Morning Pavlos, thank you very much. I am able get the code to work as long as I hard code the "hey" or "@hey" into the pattern.test(). However, when I use a variable, it always comes back as true always. Any thoughts?

Comment: var password = document.getElementsByName("pwd1")[0].value
   
var pattern = new RegExp(/^[^@]+$/);
var password1 = pattern.test(password)
   
alert(password)
alert(password1)

Comment: what do those searches equate to? right now the regex is coded to only check for "@" characters so if it doesn't have an @ it will be true; you need to add your own characters to customize it.

Comment: take a look at the code pen for this working example:https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/vYLeYqp?editors=1011 right now only "@" is defined as a special character and will return false if used.

Comment: Greeting Pavlos, thank you. I was reading the true and false backwards. I have it programmed and working now! Many thanks.